# C# ASPX: How to get a Parent page's inherited property in a Control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, properties, inherited

I have an aspx page that inherits a master page which has a protected property. Like this:

masterpage
{
protected string propX..
}

MyPage : masterpage

---myControl:UserControl

In myControl code-behind I'd like to access propX

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to cast the `Page` property of `myControl` class to `MyPage` class?

> string value = ((MyPage)this.Page).propX

And if you want to access this property from other class (like `myControl`), the access modifier of property `propX` should be set to `internal` or `public`

I've assumed, that you've placed `myControl` object on `MyPage` page.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly change the access modifiers for the string.  Maybe set it to internal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're inheriting from the master page?  Adding the MasterPage directive doesn't mean that it inherits from it.  Usually an aspx page should directly or indirectly inherit from System.Web.UI.Page.

The master pages aren't "inherited" which means that protected members cannot be accessed from the page class (or control class).  Your best option is to make the property public or internal.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. masterpage is just a class I created that inherits System.Web.UI.Page, and in masterpage i do my init work, then set MyPage:masterpage. I tried your suggestion of internal and it does not work.

Comment: ahh ok.  You will never be able to access a protected property from your UserControl.  Protected properties can only be accessed from classes that directly inherit from them.  internal properties can only be accessed by other classes in the same assembly/project.  If your UserControl and MasterPage are in different assemblies/projects then your only option it to set the property to public.  If they are in the same assembly and internal doesn't work then there must be some other problem - maybe a complete code sample would help.